# Spring Cloud PubSub can't publish to queue

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, publish-subscribe

I have an implementation that is listening from a queue and publishing to multiple queues. So I've implemented a generic interface to send messages to different topics by passing their names.

**Assumptions:**

- I'm using Google Cloud Pubsub
- spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies version: 1.1.3.RELEASE
- spring-cloud-dependencies version: Greenwich.RELEASE
- spring-integration-core version: 5.1.7.RELEASE
- spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub version: 1.1.3.RELEASE

**What am I doing?**
I'm listening to a queue and doing some logic after which I send ack messages manually to the same queue (can see the consumer.ack() on the method below), and two other messages to other queues (email triggering queue and asynchronous acking to other micro-service).
What I'm doing wrong I could't manage to find a way around, I've searched a lot and tried different things.

**Spring properties**

```
spring.cloud.gcp:
  project-id: theProjectId
  credentials:
    location: XXX.json
    scopes: DEFAULT_SCOPES
  pubsub:
    enabled: true
    publisher:
      retry:
        total-timeout-seconds: 120
        initial-retry-delay-second: 5
    subscriber:
      executor-threads: 1
      initial-retry-delay-seconds: 20
```

**StackTrace:**

```
org.springframework.cloud.gcp.pubsub.core.PubSubException: Sending Spring message failed.; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=byte[105], headers={gcp_pubsub_acknowledgement=org.springframework.cloud.gcp.pubsub.integration.inbound.PubSubInboundChannelAdapter$1@37a56117, id=2141149b-b1fd-6f35-55a8-XXXXXXXX, gcp_pubsub_topic=xxx-dev, gcp_pubsub_original_message=PushedAcknowledgeablePubsubMessage{projectId='theprojectId', subscriptionName='xxx-dev', message=data: "{\"eventId\":22,\"serviceName\":\"nameService\",\"eventName\":\"VISIT_EVENT\",\"payload\":null,\"accountId\":3}"
attributes {
  key: "gcp_pubsub_topic"
  value: "xxx-dev"
}
message_id: "8542727XXXXXX"
publish_time {
  seconds: 1573833888
  nanos: 57000000
}
}, timestamp=1573845386667}]
    at org.springframework.cloud.gcp.pubsub.integration.inbound.PubSubInboundChannelAdapter.consumeMessage(PubSubInboundChannelAdapter.java:157)
    at org.springframework.cloud.gcp.pubsub.core.subscriber.PubSubSubscriberTemplate.lambda$subscribeAndConvert$1(PubSubSubscriberTemplate.java:152)
    at com.google.cloud.pubsub.v1.MessageDispatcher$4.run(MessageDispatcher.java:438)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
```

To not include all the stack trace, other important lines:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: null
```

**Config**

```
@Configuration
public class GoogleCloud {

    private final GoogleProperties googleProperties;

    public GoogleCloud(final GoogleProperties googleProperties) {
        this.googleProperties = googleProperties;
    }

    @Bean
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "pubsubOutputChannel")
    public MessageHandler messageSender(final PubSubOperations pubSubTemplate) {
        return new PubSubMessageHandler(pubSubTemplate, "doesNotMatter");
    }

    @Bean
    public PubSubInboundChannelAdapter scheduleEventsChannelAdapter(@Qualifier("schedulerChannel") final MessageChannel outputChannel,
                                                                    final PubSubOperations pubSubTemplate) {
        final PubSubInboundChannelAdapter adapter = new PubSubInboundChannelAdapter(pubSubTemplate, googleProperties.getExecuteEvent());
        adapter.setOutputChannel(outputChannel);
        adapter.setAckMode(AckMode.MANUAL);
        return adapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public Storage customStorage() {
        return StorageOptions.getDefaultInstance().getService();
    }
}
```

**Listener**

```
 @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "schedulerChannel")
    public void handleMessage(final Message<String> message) {
        final ScheduledEvent scheduledEvent;
        try {
            scheduledEvent = objectMapper.readValue(message.getPayload(), ScheduledEvent.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error parsing message from queue");
            return;
        }

        BasicAcknowledgeablePubsubMessage consumer = (BasicAcknowledgeablePubsubMessage) message.getHeaders().get(GcpPubSubHeaders.ORIGINAL_MESSAGE);
        if (isNull(consumer)) {
            LOGGER.error("Failed to get message headers");
            return;
        }

        var eventName = scheduledEvent.getEventName();
        var accountId = scheduledEvent.getAccountId();
        myAwesomeService.doStuff(acountId,eventName);

        consumer.ack();
        queuePublisher.send(googleProperties.getSchedulerAcknowledge(),
                queuePublisher.convertObjectToString(new AcknowledgeEvent(scheduledEvent.getEventId())));
    }
```

**QueuePublisher**

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class QueuePublisher implements PubSubOutBoundGateway {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(QueuePublisher.class);

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    private final PubSubOutBoundGateway pubSubOutBoundGateway;

    public QueuePublisher(final ObjectMapper objectMapper,
                          final PubSubOutBoundGateway pubSubOutBoundGateway) {
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
        this.pubSubOutBoundGateway = pubSubOutBoundGateway;
    }

    @Override
    public void send(final String topic, final String message) {
        pubSubOutBoundGateway.send(topic, message);
    }

    public String convertObjectToString(final Object object) {
        try {
            return objectMapper.writeValueAsString(object);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error converting object to string:{}", e);
            throw new BadRequestException();
        }
    }
}
```

**PubSubOutBoundGateway**

```
@MessagingGateway(defaultRequestChannel = "pubsubOutputChannel")
public interface PubSubOutBoundGateway {

    void send(@Header(GcpPubSubHeaders.TOPIC) String topic, String message);
}
```

Comment: did you resolved your issue ?

Comment: Yes. I removed all the custom configurations of time like total-timeout-seconds and it started working. Didn't had the time to try to improve them again. Now the only issue is the multiple delivery that happens a lot! I'm handling that on my side as well.